# Voice and Message in same response using Twilio Functions

Tags: node.js, function, runtime, twilio

I am migrating from Tropo to Twilio.  I have a need to send an SMS to a monitored phone number while parsing a voice call (menu system).

The flow should be:
1. Incoming Voice call
2. Function sends SMS to one or more cell phones //alerts there is a voice call
3. Voice IVR system takes over and processes call

Using the Twilio Runtime functions (twilio's hosted node.js) I seem to be unable to combine both of these needs into a single function as the callback looks for a single twiml object. Further I also seem to be unable to send an SMS from within a voice call.

Is there example code anywhere, or is there solid documentation that might help me achieve my goal?

The following code works, but I have been advised by Twilio tech support not to use the SMS verb as its future viability is not guaranteed.

> exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
>
> let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
>
> twiml.say("Hello World");   // respond to voice caller
>     twiml.sms({to:"+19735551212"},"Hello SMS!!");   // send SMS
>
> callback(null, twiml);
>
> }

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with Twilio Studio (https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/), perhaps a "Send Message" widget followed by a "Run Function" widget.

Comment: I was able to get it working in Studio similar to your suggestion.  I was not however able to figure out how to share variables between widgets, or create a programmatic loop.  Larger goal is to run through an array and send several people a notice via SMS.  Any pointers on documentation?  I couldnt find much.

Comment: Twilio's blog is a good place to learn more about Twilio Studio. Here is one blog where you can find more about using/passing parameters (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/custom-javascript-twilio-functions-code-studio-flows.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than use the TwiML to do both the call routing and the message sending, you can send messages with the REST API and use the TwiML just for the voice routing.

For example:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    client.messages.create({  // Send SMS
        to: "+19735551212",
        from: event.From,
        body: "Hello from SMS"
    }).then(() => {  // When request to send SMS is complete, deal with the caller
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        twiml.say("Hello World");   // respond to voice caller
        callback(null, twiml);
    })    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Phil.  I had tried something similar, and in this case as well I was not able to get the code to execute.  

Runtime Functions are showing the following in the logs:  

 "runtime application timed out"  

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you share the code you’re using? It’s hard to debug without it. One suggestion: if your api calls are not successful, are you catching the error and returning something to the callback?

Comment: The code I pasted initially works (albeit using my own cellphone number instead of the example one). Next, I copied and pasted your example into Runtime Functions and changed the "to" to my own cellphone. The call doesnt answer (it fails gracefully to my "Primary Handler Fails" Webhook), and the logs throw the "runtime application timed out" message.  Looking at your example the logic makes sense so I'm not sure why its failing.  As mentioned above, my longer term goal is to loop an array and send several SMS messages. For starters I'm just looking to unit test this until I understand it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, apologies for getting the wrong number in the message sending! I do recommend you catch the errors and return them to the callback so that they are logged and you can recognise this sort of issue. Sorry I didn't add that either.

Comment: I hadn't been returning errors.. mostly because I'm not sure how within this context.  It might help with the next issue I'm experiencing as I'm trying to call the client.messages.create() in a loop (unsuccessful) and recursively (unsuccessful).  Goal it to have multiple "to" targets for the sms.

Comment: Ok, to return an error, you need to `catch` it in the promise and return the error as the first parameter to the `callback` function. Like: `client.messages.create(...).then(result => { ... }).catch(error => { callback(error); })`. And for looping, try using a `map` over the array of numbers and `Promise.all` to wait for them all to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a single iteration.  The example @philnash posted above was correct with one semantic exception.  The "from" parameter should be using "event.To" or "event.Called" as Twilio requires a valid Twilio number.  "event.From" in my case was my cell phone and not a vaild Twilio number.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    client.messages.create({  // Send SMS
        to: "+19735551212",
        from: event.Called,  // **must be a valid Twilio number **
        body: "Hello from SMS"
    }).then(function(message) {
        console.log(event.Called);
        console.log(message.sid);
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        twiml.say("How now brown cow ");
        callback(null, twiml);
    });  
}
```